# Is OpenGl still supported in C?

Tags: opengl

I'm reading the OpenGl superbible 3th edition (well I plan to) and it's all in C. Since this book was written in 2004 and all the other later versions are written in C++, i was wondering whether or not OpenGl is still supported in C, and whether the relevant downloads required will still be available. I want to do it this way, because I'm more comfortable with C, and I'm still learning C++.

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL is natively written in C. For C++ you usually use wrappers.
So yeah, don't worry, it'll work just fine in C as always :)

I would suggest to read a more modern book though, a lot has changed with OpenGL 3+.

Comment: I don't see the problem with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenGL natively in either C or C++, the API has always been implemented in C.

You can also use OpenGL calls in C++ exactly the same way you would in C.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

The standard OpenGL headers are all written for C, although the book is written in C++ so that they can use their supplied classes.  Most windowing frameworks, including SDL and GLFW, as well as GLEW for loading extensions, are also written in C.  Even SFML has a set of C bindings.

Comment: Reassuring. One question: would it still be ok to read a book that was written 10 years ago, or has OpenGl altered dramatically that anything from 2004 would seem alien?

Comment: I would advise that you read the newest (6th) edition.  Although the library it provides for windowing and other utilities is C++, if you're not using it all the rest of the code is pure C (or at least easily ported).  You'll miss out on the cool features like compute shaders, deferred rendering, and tessellation if not!